# Pixel relocation, showing side-by-side

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

I want to read individual pixels from one image and "relocate" them to another image. I basically want to simulate how it would be if I grabbed pixel by pixel from one image and "move" them to a blank canvas. Turning the pixels I grab from the original image white.

This is what I have right now, I'm able to read the pixels from the image and create a copy (which comes out saturated for some reason) of it.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ImageTest
{
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
{
   //create buffered image object img
   File oldImgFile = new File("/path/to/image/shrek4life.jpg");
   BufferedImage oldImg = null;
   BufferedImage newImg = null;
   try{
      oldImg = ImageIO.read(oldImgFile);
   }catch(IOException e){}
   newImg = new BufferedImage(oldImg.getWidth(), oldImg.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
   File f = null;
   try
   {
      for(int i = 0; i < oldImg.getWidth(); i++){
          for(int j = 0; j < oldImg.getHeight(); j++){
              //get the rgb color of the old image and store it the new
              Color c = new Color(oldImg.getRGB(i, j));
              int r = c.getRed();
              int g = c.getGreen();
              int b = c.getBlue();

              int col = (r<<16) | (g<<8) | b;
              newImg.setRGB(i, j, col);
          }
      }
      //write image
      f = new File("newImg.jpg");
      ImageIO.write(newImg, "jpg", f);
   }catch(IOException e){
     System.out.println("Error: " + e);
   }
}//main() ends here
}//class ends here
```

And I would like to basically slow the process down and display it happening. But I'm not sure how to do that. Would I need to use to accomplish this ? I'm somewhat new to threading but I think I would need multiple threads to handle the painting of both pictures.

Comment: As you don't display anything in your current code, it's not entirely clear how you envision this... But what I would do, using Swing, is to display the original image next to the blank copy. Then start a Swing timer with a fixed rate, that copies one pixel, increments x/y variables, and invokes `update()` on the component displaying the copy.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would like to mention you are working in a very inefficient way. You are creating a Color, decomposing a pixel in its channels, and moving to the new image by a bit-shift. It is easier if you work directly with the integer the whole time (and more efficient).

I will assume the image "/path/to/image/shrek4life.jpg" has ARGB color space. I recommend ensure this, because if the old image does not have this color space you  should make a [conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space#Conversion).

When you create the new image, you create it as [ARGB color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space), so each channel is expressed in a byte of the int, first byte for Alpha, second byte for red, third byte for green and the last one for blue.

I think you forgot the alpha channel when you manipulated the old image pixel to move it into the new image.

With this explanation in mind, I think you can change your code to increase the efficiency, like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < oldImg.getWidth(); i++){
  for(int j = 0; j < oldImg.getHeight(); j++){
    int pixel = oldImg.getRGB(i,j);
    newImg.setRGB(i, j, pixel );
    //If you like to get more control over the pixels and print
    //you can decompose the pixel using Color as you already do
    //But when you understand fully the process I recommend erase it
    Color c = new Color(pixel);
    //Print the color or do whatever you like
  }
}
```

About how to display the process of pixel relocation:

**In process**:

1. You can print the changed pixel as a number with its position in image (discouraged). `System.out.println("pixel"+pixel+" X:"+i+" Y:"+j);`
2. Use this [tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/java-images) in baeldung to print an image. I suggest [draw a rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877882/draw-rectangle-in-jpanel) with the color of the image and wait for a key press (enter, for example) using [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). After the key was press, you can load the next pixel, an so on.
3. If a single rectangle with just one pixel has little information, I suggest add an array of rectangles to draw several pixels in a time. Even you can print an image, and see the process pixel by pixel, using Scanner to mark each step.
4. As @haraldK suggest, you can use Swing to display de relocation image. Through  swing timer and invokes `update()`

**Post process**:

5. Save the image in a file. To improve the speed of process, I suggest save a few pixels (10 - 100).

Comment: Alright, thanks for the pointer on the inefficiency. Fixed that. And my picture actually doesn't have an alpha channel that's why it was coming out in a weird color.

Comment: My question still stands though. I need a way of displaying this relocation process, so to say. Like, I want to show this while it's happening, as opposed to running the program, waiting for it to finish and then opening the image.

Comment: @MarcoNeves I improve the response to add several ways to display the relocation process step by step.